# why doesn't setfacl give executable permission?

Tags: permissions, chmod, setfacl

I ran

`sudo setfacl -d -m g::rwx /tmp`

then went into `/tmp` and created a file and looked at its permissions:

`-rw-rw-rw-.  1 jm wheel         0 Aug 24 10:26 test_file`

then I ran

`sudo chmod g+rwx test_file`

and looked at the permissions:

`-rwxrwxrwx. 1 jm wheel         0 Aug 24 10:26 test_file`

shouldn't the first command `setfacl -d -m g::rws /tmp` have given it executable permissions in the first place? why did I have to run `chmod`to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why did I have to run `chmod` to get them?

Because you are doing it wrong! 
Try:

```
setfacl -Rdm g:maulinglawns:rwx tmp/
touch tmp/foo
getfacl tmp/foo 
# file: tmp/foo
# owner: maulinglawns
# group: maulinglawns
user::rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:maulinglawns:rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

And here is what `ls` says (note the `+` sign at the end, it indicates that we indeed *have* an acl set):

```
ls -l tmp/
totalt 0
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 maulinglawns maulinglawns 0 aug 24 18:55 foo
```

Please read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) for setfacl. Especially the **ACL ENTRIES** part.

Comment: I don't get it, after setting the acl, it still won't allow me to execute the file without the execute permission?